# OS X mount local directory

Tags: macos, unix, mount

Is it possible to mount a local directory into another one? Using Perforce, I want to do something equivalent to symlinking a directory, but in a way that fools it into thinking it's really just another directory in the project.

I would like to do something like:

```
mount /foo/bar /home/foo/bar
```

Is this possible, and if so what options do I need to give it?

Comment: What about moving this to apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) seems like what you're after...

Comment: This is old, but for the sake of posterity, thought I'd add that I've had problems with data corruption with bindfs. And performance issues.

Comment: (Dang sorry for the added comment; I accidentally hit return which committed the comment and then waited more than five minutes to update it. Sigh). Anyway, wanted to note that as mentioned below, HFS+ supports hard-links between directories (with limitations) and while the native ln command won't do it, the gnu link command (in macports as well as elsewhere) will.

Comment: Thanks smparkes, I'm not a mac user, so it's good to have more authoritative feedback.

Comment: Disadvantage of fuse is that it do not support inotify events. If source updated, while App watching for updates in destination, it will not receive updates.

Comment: I can't get bindfs to work with MacOS Catalina (https://github.com/mpartel/bindfs/issues/83)

Comment: @Thomas works fine for me using macOS 10.15.3, though I note you have to use absolute paths when mounting. I installed via the homebrew cask.  Performance issues make it unusable in practice though, long delays just doing `ls` from the terminal: --multithreaded helps with that but any directory searching inside is also impractically slow. Even nfs performs far better.

Comment: @DavidNugent, I will try with absolute paths; thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
mount localhost:/path1 /path2
```

will use NFS.

There is a lot of things that may go wrong with NFS, it would be insane to handle them in this answer, better ask on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and read [man mount_nfs(8)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_nfs.8.html).

Comment: Getting "Connection refused", any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Norswap Please open your question on apple.stackexchange.com aka [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Norswap I know this is a bit old, but this works. I went ahead and investigated, and [posted my findings here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197029/how-do-you-mount-bind-a-local-directory/197030#197030). NFS is the answer; just a matter of a little configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can only mount different filesystems under the directory tree.  You may be able to achieve what you're looking to do by hard linking the directories.  OS X allows hard linking directories and to perforce it would like like different directories

Comment: It should be noted this won't work anymore in APFS, which is currently the default filesystem. Since macOS Mojave, all drives are upgraded to APFS. Only HFS+ supports hard link.

Answer (score 2):

The BSD (and thus Darwin/OSX) method of achieving this is [nullfs](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nullfs&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE). It's not in a standard build of OS X, but perhaps it's possible to build from source if you have the time to play around with it.

Comment: `sudo mount -t nullfs` doesn't work for me

Comment: I have implemented a compatible mount_nullfs [here](https://github.com/JamaicanMoose/mount_nullfs) however due to entitlements it requires disabling both SIP and AMFI.

Answer (score -6):

To make a hard link from one directory to another, run:

```
$ ln /foo/bar /home/foo/bar
```

It is important to note that from the OS's perspective, both links are treated equally. You can delete `/foo/bar` and `/home/foo/bar` will remain a valid reference to the data on disk.

Comment: Hardlinking directories is evil!!! (Unless you're very careful...)

Comment: you can _not_ hardlink directories in OSX via 'ln'

Comment: Whoops. Shame on me for not actually running the command. Point taken.

Comment: Time Machine actually uses hard links to directories, so it must somehow be possible.

Comment: It can be done, but you have to write code to do it... Some example code (as well as the conditions placed on directory hard links) is about halfway down on this page: http://www.osxbook.com/blog/2008/11/09/hfsdebug-40-and-new-hfs-features/ (search for the word "experimentation")